# Debugging a Promise in Node.js/ VScode (Newbie)

Tags: node.js, selenium

I am quite new to node.js .. and I want to debug something and get the result in a watch while debugging ( in VS Code )

I am using selenium webdriver to get an element , then I want to inspect those elements using a watch in debug.

code is:

```
var divs = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='statementLines']/div"))
```

I want ( for example ) to see the result of :

```
divs[0].getText()
```

All I get if I put that in a watch is "Managed Promise" .  I am sure there must be a way to easily result the result in a watch without having to go through the whole program to this point..?

Comment: Is that the complete code? `await` only works inside a function marked as `async`. It does not work outside

Comment: Thanks. divs[0].getText()  <<--   I want to get the value in a watch.  

If I do it in the code , I can use await divs[0].getText()

But I can't figure out how to wrap this in a function and return it in the debug watch.

Comment: Ah. OK. So let's assume that `await` works. First put a breakpoint at the await and trigger it - the reason for this is to get into the context of the function the await is in. Then, when the breakpoint is triggered just watch `divs[0].getText()`. Normally you cannot do this until you're inside the function because `divs[0]` does not exist outside the scope of the function.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. divs[0[.getText()  does not show a result.  It shows "Managed promise"

Comment: Wait, so `getText()` is also a promise? Then you need to await it as well

Comment: You can't use await in a watch .. it say it must be in an async function ( even if my breakpoint is inside an async function.

Comment: If you can't use await then use a `.then()`. I'm personally avoiding async/await until they're better supported by all the different engines and tools. Regular promises are good enough.